# Can't use dot in table name with TypeORM and Oracle

Tags: node.js, oracle, nestjs, typeorm

I create entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'MYTABLE.TITLE' })
export class MyEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

....
}
```

And when execute in my service

```
this.baseRepo.find()
```

in logs I have got some worst query, smth like this shit:
SELECT "MyEntity".id ... FROM "MYTABLE"."NAME"

What is problem, why I haven't access to table with names separated with dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use @Entity({ name: 'TITLE', schema: 'MYTABLE' })

Answer (score 0):

If this has something to do with an Oracle database (apparently, it does  as you used that tag), then: dot can't be part of table name:

```
SQL> create table mytable.name (id number);
create table mytable.name (id number)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'MYTABLE' does not exist
```

**unless** you enclose it into double quotes:

```
SQL> create table "myTAbLe.nAme" (id number);

Table created.
```

but that means that you have to enclose it into double quotes, following **exactly** the same letter case every time you reference it:

```
SQL> select * from mytable.name;
select * from mytable.name
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from "mytable.name";
select * from "mytable.name"
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from "MyTAbLe.nAme";
select * from "MyTAbLe.nAme"
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from "myTAbLe.nAme";

no rows selected

SQL>
```

That's why it is - generally speaking - a really, Really, REALLY bad idea to do so in Oracle. Create it without double quotes (of course, don't use a dot - what's wrong with an underline?), use any letter case you want (because Oracle will store it into the data dictionary in uppercase), reference it using any letter case you want:

```
SQL> create table mytable_name(id number);

Table created.

SQL> select * From mytable_name;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from MYTAble_NaMe;

no rows selected

SQL> select * from MYTABLE_NAME;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: Yeah, but it's already existed table :( And it's weird, but it generally works SELECT * FROM MYTABLE.TABLE WHERE ID = 1